# regex for matching german postal codes but not a

Tags: ruby, regex, postal-code

following string:

> 23434 5465434
>
> 58495 / 46949345
>
> 58495 - 46949345
>
> 58495 / 55643
>
> d **44444** ssdfsdf
>
> **64784**
>
> **45643** dfgh
>
> 58495/55643
>
> 48593/48309596
>
> 675643235
>
> 34565435 34545

it only want to extract the bold ones. its a five digit number(german).
it should not match telephone numbers `43564 366334` or `45433 / 45663`,etc as in my example above.

i tried something like `^\b\d{5}` but thats not a good beginning.

some hints for me to get this working?

thanks for all hints

Comment: please add additional information how to tell why some 5-digit numbers are acceptable and others are not. Are they a specific range? Is there a specific format? The more information you provide, the better the answers people can provide. As is, people are having to guess what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a negative look-ahead assertion to avoid the matches with phone numbers.

```
\b[0124678][0-9]{4}\b(?!\s?[ \/-]\s?[0-9]+)
```

If you're using Ruby 1.9, you can add a negative look-behind assertion as well.

Comment: Just what it sounds like. The (?!...) part above is looking ahead and refusing to match if the ... conditions are met. In Ruby 1.9, we can use (?<!...) to similarly look backwards.

Comment: I see this regexp floating around in a lot of places, but it's NOT correct. The problem is that any German zipcode which starts with a 3, 5 or 9 isn't seen as valid, although they are perfectly valid and also used. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Germany

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what distinguishes the number you're trying to search for.

Based on the example string you gave, it looks like you just want:
`^(\d{5})\n`

Which matches lines that start with 5 digits and contain nothing else.

You might want to permit some spaces after the first 5 digits (but nothing else):
`^(\d{5})\s*\n`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about the specified rules.  But if you want lines that start with 5 digits and do not contain additional digits, this may work:

```
^(\d{5})[^\d]*$
```

If leading white space is okay, then:

```
^\s*(\d{5})[^\d]*$
```

Here is the [Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/DbRYl6D6eJ) that shows the result.

Comment: looks promising, but i dont want to match the charakters in your second match, also `d 44444 ssdfsdf` should match =/ very complicated

Answer (score 0):

```
^\D*(\d{5})(\s(\D)*$|()$)
```

This should (it's untested) match:

- line starting with five digits (or some non-digits and then five digits), then
  a space, and ending with some non-numbers
- line starting and ending with five
  digits (or some non-digits and then five digits)

\1 would be the five digits

\2 would be the whole second half, if any

\3 would be the word after the digits, if any

edited to fit the asker's edited question

edit again: I came up with a much more elegant solution:

```
^\D*(\d{5})\D*$
```

Comment: also a good start. but it also matches charakters and it should work if the line is starting with something else then a digit (check edit) your matches => http://www.rubular.com/r/9FUAYtkP4X

Comment: Actually, I just came up with a better solution. Check the post.

Comment: hm sorry. not working for me, because it includes charakters. whitespace is no problem, but charakters are.

Comment: Honestly, you're going to have to be way more specific. No one knows what you mean by "charakters". They're _all_ characters.